# Select different image source for multiple targets at pre built phase

Tags: ios, xcode

A Project has multiple targets with single source code.

Each target should display different banner image.

Want to choose the relative banner image source automatically according to the bundle identifier at pre built phase.

Comment: Is that banner shown in the app ? If yes, can't you just programmatically select the image ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create 2 folders in assets catalog with names of targets
2. Move banners in folders , Banners must have same name
3. Select banner for Target A and from "Taget membership" uncheck Tagret B
4. Select banner for Target B and from "Taget membership" uncheck Tagret A
5. Build and run )